# Почему при вызове функции map подсчет цифр некорректен?

Tags: python, map

```
a = str([1,1])
b = list(map(len, a))
print(b)
```

Comment: `a = str([1,1])` а для чего вы список чисел в строковое представление приводите? Добавьте в вопрос описание задачи

Answer (score 2):

а что вы хотели получить?

```
str([1, 1])
```

переведет список `[1, 1]` в строку `"[1, 1]"`

это можно проверить сделав обратную операцию

```
list(str([1, 1]))
```

и получить `['[', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ']']`

дальше вы применяете `map` к символам строки `['[', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ']']`

длина символа - 1, всего в строке 6 символов, в результаты вы получаете новый список из 6 единичек `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Вы написав `a = str([1, 1])` превращаете весь массив в строку, вам надо отдельно на каждый элемент применить функцию `str`

```
a = map(str, [123, 52])
b = list(map(len, a)) 
print(b)
```

вывод:

> `[3, 2]`